# SharePoint pnp richtexteditor font size

Tags: typescript, sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

I have a  react spx solution that uses pnp rich-text control. Is it possible to change the default font size or choose the font sizes the user can select? I failed to find examples, but this should be possible, seeing how other editors work.

```
<RichText isEditMode={true} value={myvalue} onChange={this.onTextChange} />
```

I tried to find options for this control but failed to google any.